# how to edit title of bulk posts?

Tags: bulk

I have got hundreds of posts published but with inappropriate titles. I want to edit/updates titles. I have those all titles in a .txt file which I want to have them on the posts. If there is any solution?? I want the fastest way. It's also so hard for me to copy/past each title to the post. I want one-click method. I have heard on some sites that it can done by exporting all posts to .csv file which can be then edited in excel to change titles and then imported to the site. but again I guess the problem is still there in excel I have to edit each column which is again a very tedious. I wish if someone could refer me wordpress plugins or any kinda excel bot which can make my work done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you produce the titles of the posts but something like:

1. Load the posts into wordpress
2. Update wp_posts using mysql

That's how I do bulk editing and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to accomplish this. It is going to be a tedious task no matter what. But this got me thinking that since you already have them published into WordPress, you could export them via the WordPress export tool. Which puts all your posts into an xml file, you would then have to edit all the titles in that file. Much easier than doing it via WordPress, where you have to quick edit each post and save. After you are done editing the xml file you could then just import the xml file. Not the best solution, but works.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. Works better than any silly plugin.